# Closed Subset of Spec$(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is a union of closed points in the Zariski topology.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to show that any proper closed subset of Spec$(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is a union of closed points in the Zariski topology. I know that the closed points in Spec$(\mathbb{C}[X])$ are exactly the ideals of the form $(X-\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and I feel like this should be enough to prove the claim but I am not sure how to argue this. 
Also, does this mean that Spec$(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is Hausdorff? I haven't seen much topology in a while and I am not sure what the best way to see this is.

Comment: No, the affine line over $\Bbb C$ is not Hausdorff ; it has the cofinite topology.

Comment: @Watson: no, the affine line $\operatorname {Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ doe not have the cofinite topology. For example the set of maximal ideals is not closed even though its complement has only one element, the generic point. However the induced subspace $\operatorname {Specmax}( \mathbb C[X])$ does indeed have the cofinite topology.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : you're right. I was thinking about the maximal spectrum, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The point of $Spec(\mathbb{C}[X])$ are irreducible ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X])$. Since $\mathbb{C}[X])$ is principal, every non zero prime ideal is generated by an irreducible polynomial $(X-\alpha)$ which is maximal and represents a closed point. The zero ideal which is dense (the generic point). So it is not separated.

Comment: One nitpick: separated could mean multiple things. Here you're using it as "satisfies the T2 separation axiom as a topological space" but there's also a version for schemes which means something very different and could be reasonably encountered soon after dealing with this sort of question.

Comment: @KReiser is right. It is better to say that $Spec(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is not Hausdorff, since  the scheme $Spec(\mathbb{C}[X])$ actually **is** separated  (like all affine schemes) in the sense of scheme theory .